# "perfect-scrollbar" (jQuery plugin) isn't initialised properly when a its container is being filled with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, perfect-scrollbar

On my page I programmatically generate a food/drinks menus from a json file with Angular.js. The problem is with the "[perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar)" used for scrolling the angular-generated content, which appears to require a scroll-wheel event to initialise on these menus. This makes it impossible to scroll on devices without a scroll-wheel. Apart from the angular-generated content other pages initialize perfect-scrollbar properly. This gave me a clue that the problem might lie with the interaction between jQuery world (perfect-scrollbar is a jQuery plugin) and Angular world.
The site is [themockingbird.co.uk](http://themockingbird.co.uk) - navigate to the "Food" and "Drinks" to see the problem in action - can't scroll the content (the perfect-scrollbar won't appear) unless with the mouse scroll-wheel.
I've written this little directive:

```
mainMenuApp.directive('scrollBar', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            $(element).perfectScrollbar();
            //element.perfectScrollbar(); - doesn't work
            //angular.element(element).perfectScrollbar(); - doesn't work
        }
    }
});
```

to facilitate the "perfect-scrollbar" via angular for the two menus, but this did not solve the problem.
How can I make the perfect-scrollbar work perfectly with angular (pun intended :)?
I appreciate your time.
cheers
Jared

Comment: I can scroll in Chrome 34 on Mac OSX without a problem using the perfect scroll bar (the scrollbar with the orange arrows I guess). In which browser have you tried it?

Comment: It works for me in Chrome & Firefox 28. Worked with both my laptop touchpad & mouse wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time your link function is executed, your *menu-food.json* and *menu-drink.json* are not arrived yet and *perfectScrollbar* needs an update at the time the data arrive, called with:

```
$(element).perfectScrollbar('update');
```

Since you have no architecture for handling the food and drinks lists as decoupled watchable values in a controller attached by your directive, you may simply broadcast an event from the root scope, listened by your directive link functions, thus updating the *perfectScrollbar* instance at the right moment.

Comment: Does the trick. Thought this would be an issue, and tried to use the 'update' before, but now I realize I was trying to do it synchronously, which of course didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: One question: How do I make sure that the event is broadcasted AFTER all ng-repeats are done?

Comment: Short way: have your event listener set a flag, and have your directive watch this flag. Longer but better way: implement controller communication via directives.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using https://github.com/itsdrewmiller/angular-perfect-scrollbar - the following "add-on directive", solved this problem:

```
.directive('psMouseOver', function () {    
    return {       
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.bind("mouseover", function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();    
                element.perfectScrollbar('update');
            });   
        }
    }
});
```

In your case however, one would just add those lines and write your directive as:

```
mainMenuApp.directive('scrollBar', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.perfectScrollbar();
            element.bind("mouseover", function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();    
                element.perfectScrollbar('update');
            }); 
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That happen in my case when Angular.js files loaded before JQuery and Perfect Scrollbar scripts files includes.

```
<script src="assets/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
```

Try to load firstly JQuery, Perfect Scrollbar, and just after AngularJS.